# IE 7 Absolute Positioning issue

Tags: css

I'm beating a dead horse with this one. I've got a set of nested divs and one in particular needs to be absolutely positioned so that it doesn't conflict with a couple of other elements. The  HTML is:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="gal_info">
        <h2>Gallery</h2>
        <div id="gal_caption">Caption goes here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="gal_imgs">    
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#gal_info{
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 width: 190px;
 height: 170px;
 padding: 10px 10px 0 30px;
 background-color: #f8fce2;
}
```

That all works perfectly in every browser except IE7. In IE7, the entire div for #gal_info disappears. I've tried checking all my positions all the way back to the `<body>` tag. I've tried adding z-indexes to elements to make it show. I cannot figure out what's going wrong, but as soon as I take out the `position: absolute;` it appears.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the CSS for `#gallery` and `div` tags in general?

Comment: `div` doesn't have any css - the `#gallery` has `position: relative`, as do all the parent divs between `#gallery` and `<body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite figure out why, but I've got it working now. I reworked the page over from scratch and it's all showing correctly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We got missing information here my friend, but just guessing, what is the position for gallery div? did you tried se it as relative?

Comment: FYI: You should use the comment feature to ask questions and not provide an answer that is a question.

Comment: see comment above - I have already added `position: relative` to the `#gallery` div and to every other containing div above it, all the way back to the `<body>` tag